# ほかの beta サイトのような "site stats" の表示はどうか？

Tags: 機能の要求

Stack Exchange の [Japanese language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) , [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)や [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) などいくつかのβサイトでは，サイトを開いた時右側に，質問数，回答数，回答率，ユーザ数，一日あたりの訪問者数からなる site stats なるものが表示されます．個人的にはこれは（とりあえず上記3サイトについては<sup>1</sup>）やる気を起こさせるよい機能だと思っているのですが，ja.stackoverflow にはないようですね．

技術的，あるいはサイト管理上の制約がないなら，導入してみてはどうでしょうか？

追記：単に情報を見たいというだけではなくて，例えば japanese.stackexchange の右側のように（画像），サイトトップの右端に表示させておけばどうだろう，というのが趣旨です．

[image: japanese.stackexchange より]

---

（1: いずれも「いい感じ」の数字が並ぶサイトなので，単純にどこにでも導入して効果のあるものでもないの，かも?）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

英語になりますが、[stackexchange.com/sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)に表示しています：

[image: 現在の統計]

もしSQLはできるなら、[data.se](http://data.stackexchange.com/)でSQLで当サイトのデータベースをクエリできます（投票等の一部を除く）。

最近のアナウンスでは[１０質問以上／日は卒業範囲](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)ですので、現在の数字はかなりいいですが、改善できるのは未回答質問を回答すること、そして投票を増えることです。

Comment: 質問文がはっきりしていませんでした．トップページ右側に表示されるもののことです（質問に追記しました）．/ answered が少ないですね．承認機能を広めたいところというかんじでしょうか．

Comment: @Yosh あ、なるほど。他のベータサイトと違って、当サイトはエリア５１のプロポーザルがありませんでした。他サイトの右側の箱をクリックするとエリア５１に接続します。そのために日本語版にはないと思いますし、そしてリンク先は英語になるために表示していないです。

Comment: あー，あれが表示されるのはエリア51 で提案があってベータに移行したサイトのみで，ja.stackoverflow はそれに入らないということでしょうか．それなら単純に「導入しようよ」っていうのは難しそうですね．

Comment: @Yosh できれば、別なメタ投稿をしてくれますか？開発者とちょっと確認してみます（簡単かどうかわかりませんが、多分エリア５１で仮のプロポーザルを作成できる等な手順もあるかもしれないです）

Comment: 遅くなりました．ちょっと accept するのを先走ってしまったかも知れません．[こういう感じ](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1871) で良かったでしょうか．