# サイトトップで，質問数や回答数などを示した統計情報を見せるのはどうか？（続）

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了

関連：[ほかの beta サイトのような "site stats" の表示はどうか？ - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1869)

[Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com), [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) などいくつかの beta サイトでは，下のようにサイトトップの右側に（つまり多くの閲覧者がある場所に），Site Stats と称して質問数，回答数，回答率などの統計情報が表示されます．

[image: japanese.stackexchange より]

個人的にはこれは，モチベーションを上げるいい作用を持っていると思います．

そこで，ここ スタック・オーバーフロー も同じように beta なので，同じものを導入するのはどうか，というのが上掲の質問でした．モデレータの [jmac](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10/jmac) さんに[コメントいただいた](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1869#comment1029_1870)ところによれば，

> 他のベータサイトと違って、当サイトは[エリア５１](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) のプロポーザルがありませんでした。他サイトの右側の箱をクリックするとエリア５１に接続します。そのため‌​に日本語版にはないと思いますし、そしてリンク先は英語になるために表示していないです。

とのことで，同じベータといっても少し事情が違うようです．

ということで，質問：

- （主にモデレータの方に:） 別の方法で，このような情報を表示させておくことはできるでしょうか？
- （一般利用者の方に:）このようなサイトの情報をトップに示すことについてどう思われますか？僕はあるといいと思いますが，モチベーションになる，邪魔だ，運営がもう少し安定して回答率も上がるのを待った方がいいのではないか，など色々あると思います．如何でしょうか．

なお，現状でも統計情報を見ることはできるようです．これについては [jmac さんに頂いた回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1870/2901) を参照してください．

Comment: 今日開発者と話して、エリア５１のリンクを外せばなんとかなるらしいです。とりあえず検討して実施するつもりですが、しばらく適用までお待ちください。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

適用しました。

翻訳は更新中ですが、とりあえず最終としては下記を使おうとしています。もし違和感を感じたら、直接[Transifex](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1680/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0%e3%81%ae%e3%83%af%e3%83%bc%e3%82%af%e3%83%95%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%82%92%e6%94%b9%e5%96%84%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86?s=3|0.1666)で治せます。

- [Site Stats: サイトの統計情報](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/%24/-1?key=c4d3406e319f31aa69bb164294ad2bdd)
- [Answered: 解決済](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/$/40288805?key=bef43a30845ab1a8e7dd32f6f7a9de3b)
- [visitors/day: 訪問／日](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/%24/-1?key=79fab988ee0203790e1521377139ab5b)

Comment: 個人的にはすごくいいと思います！